# how to send json data from html page to node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

i want to send some json data from my client page to server page of node.js,
 here i have my server page :

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function(req,res){
   res.send('recieved request');
   console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(8081);
console.log('listening on 8081');
```

client page:

```js
var name ='someName';
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(this.readyState== 4 && this.status == 200){
  console.log(this.responseText);
 }
};
xhttp.setRequestHeader({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
xhttp.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8081', true);
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({'name' : name}));
```

I got the result as a null json {}.

NOTE: I don't want to about submission of a form , i just want to send JSON data from html file to node.js file.

Comment: i got the response on html page as received request, but get a null json on server page.

Answer (score 1):

The correct signature for a call to `XMLHTTPRequest#setRequestHeader` is `setRequestHeader(header, value)`;

Change

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
```

to

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader